# Оптимизировать код по сохранению Entity

Tags: java, hibernate

Имеются две Entity, ссылающиеся друг на друга соответствующими полями отмеченными аннотациями

```
@Entity
Player {
    @OneToOne
    private User user;
}

@Entity
User{
    @OneToOne
    private Player player;
}
```

Как возможно упростить код по сохранению?

```
try (Session session = cfg.buildSessionFactory().openSession())
{
    session.beginTransaction();
    Player player = user.getPlayer();
    session.save(player);
    session.save(user);
    player.setUser(user);
    session.save(player);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

Уверен, что это возможно, а то хоть у меня и работает, но дюже не красиво...

Comment: Сначала один объект Player сохраняем, и User получает player_id в базе, потом "в ручную" Player'у снова присваиваю Usera чтобы он уже user_id получил... Хотя по идее (как я хотел бы думать), должен один раз сохраняться только user и все...  (остальное должен делать hibernate сам) и вполне вероятно эта связка делается через аннотации... Был бы рад чтобы подсказали направление. Спасибо.

Comment: Чистый хибернейт используете?

Comment: это вопрос к тому, что лучше сразу через... SpringData, например, пробовать смотреть решения? пока только-только стал глубже стараться понять тему...

Comment: Сделайте Cascade type Persist и сохраняя одного юзера, автоматически сохранится и второй.

Answer (score 0):

После нескольких экспериментов пришло такое решение

в User чуть изменить поле player:

```
private Player player = new Player();
```

тогда при сохранении объектов, код можно сделать в две строчки:

```
try (Session session = cfg.buildSessionFactory().openSession())
{
    session.beginTransaction();

    session.save    ( user );
    user.getPlayer().setUser(user);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

Используется тот факт, что пока сессия не закрыта изменения объектов "автоматом" заносятся в базу (и это дополнительно описывать не нужно)

Comment: не знаю кто минус поставил, но хоть бы аргументировали, добавили бы свое решение...